# Upload data to Redshift with PySpark

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-redshift, etl

I have a script written on pyspark. What I try to do is read *.csv file from S3 bucket in AWS using pyspark.

I create a DataFrame with all data, select all the columns I need and cast them types my Redshift table expects:

```
    mapping = [('id', StringType), ('session', StringType), ('ip', StringType)]

    df = spark.read.\
        format("csv").\
        option("header", True).\
        load(f"...")
    
    rows_to_map = [field[0] for field in columns_mapping]
    # We need to select only specific columns
    mapped_df = df.select(*rows_to_map)
    # Now need to cast types
    for mapping in columns_mapping:
        mapped_df = mapped_df.withColumn(mapping[0], mapped_df[mapping[0]].cast(mapping[1]()))
    
    mapped_df.printSchema()
    
    mapped_df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.redshift").\
        option("url", "...").\
        option("dbtable", "...").\
        option("tempdir", "...").\
        option("user", "...").\
        option("password", "...").\
        option("aws_iam_role", "...").\
        mode("append").\
        save()
```

And I receive an error during inserting data into redshift: Check 'stl_load_errors' system table for details.

There I see that it tries to read columns from csv randomly(almost).

SCHEMA of my dataframe:

```
|-- id: string (nullable = true) 
|-- session: string (nullable = true) 
|-- ip: string (nullable = true)
...
```

As you can see by first rows it goes like that id -> session -> ip ...
But my Redshift table shows schema with the same fields but in different order. First 3 rows:

```
|-- id: string (nullable = true) 
|-- created_at: long (nullable = true) 
|-- session: string (nullable = true)
```

As a result on the second column he cries that I'm trying to write STRING into LONG column. Instead of created_at he read from the file session.

Question: does order of columns in my DataFrame(tmp_file) is critical?
Any solution for that? It will take too much time process each file.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a list of column names in your redshift table, and rearrange the columns in the Spark dataframe before writing:

```
# redshift table columns, in correct order
colnames = ['id', 'created_at', 'session', ...]   

mapped_df = mapped_df.select(colnames)
mapped_df.write(...)
```

Comment: This is what I thought to do. But isn’t it’s strange that such issue happens? I really try to find any explanation from redshift side why he maps directly as he has in the schema but index. Not by column name

Comment: @Mark I think Spark dataframe writers tend to write columns in the order of the dataframe, instead of matching column names from the schema. I'm not sure why, but that's how it generally works.